# AFNetworking what to do with _NSInlineData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, soap, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to connect to a server using soap request to get some data. I've setup the following:

```
NSString *soapmsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:ns=\"http://www.schneider-electric.com/common/dataexchange/2011/05\">"
                        @"<soap:Header/>"
                        @"<soap:Body>"
                            @"<ns:GetValuesRequest>"
                                @"<ns:GetValuesIds>"
                                    @"<ns:Id>%@</ns:Id>"
                                @"</ns:GetValuesIds>"
                            @"</ns:GetValuesRequest>"
                        @"</soap:Body>"
                     @"</soap:Envelope>",
                     KTempId];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:KUrl]];
[request addValue: @"application/soap+xml; charset=utf8"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", KUrl] forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[soapmsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:kWebPassword password:kWebPassword persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation.securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];
[operation.securityPolicy setValidatesDomainName:NO];
[operation setCredential:credential];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, id  _Nonnull responseObject)
{
    NSLog(@"type: %@", [responseObject class]);
    NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
    NSString *tmpString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"dict count: %lu\n And string: %@", (unsigned long)[responseDictionary count], tmpString);
}
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, NSError * _Nonnull error)
{
    NSLog(@"Failure \n%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];

[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:operation];
```

This works and returns the following NSLogs:

> type: _NSInlineData
>   dict count: 0

```
 "And string: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"
"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:EWSv122="http://www.schneider-electric.com/common/dataexchange/2011/05/DataExchangeInterface/Fault" xmlns:EWSv121="http://www.schneider-electric.com/common/dataexchange/2011/05">"
"<SOAP-ENV:Header></SOAP-ENV:Header>"
    "<SOAP-ENV:Body>"
        "<EWSv121:GetValuesResponse>"
            "<EWSv121:GetValuesItems>"
                "<EWSv121:ValueItem>
                "<EWSv121:Id>01/HC RT/Verdieping1/Noord/201/T</EWSv121:Id>"
                    "<EWSv121:State>0</EWSv121:State>"
                    "<EWSv121:Value>20.769998550415</EWSv121:Value>"
                "</EWSv121:ValueItem>"
            "</EWSv121:GetValuesItems>"
        "<EWSv121:GetValuesErrorResults>"
        "</EWSv121:GetValuesErrorResults>"
        "</EWSv121:GetValuesResponse>"
    "</SOAP-ENV:Body>"
"</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"
```

So the connection is working. But I'm only getting an NSString back and can't seem to parse it to an NSDictionary or whatsoever.

I tried setting:

```
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```

But then I get an error saying:

Failure 
Request failed: unacceptable content-type: application/soap+xml

So what should I do with the responseObject?

EDIT:
I added an NSError to the NSJsonSerializer and this is what it logs:

Error parsing: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Comment: Are you waiting for JSON or XML? Since you post XML, I guess that you're awaiting for XML answers. You didn't use the error parameter of `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`. If you could also post the "andString:" part of your log to show what I guess would be XML (try by quoting it).

Comment: Hi Larme,

I added the andString part to to Opening Post, I don't really know what to expect since there is no documentation of the service i'm trying to connect to. I've also tried using:
operation.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];

But that also returns:
Failure Request failed: unacceptable content-type: application/soap+xml

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the asker resolved it with a self-answer providing no explanation whatsoever.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Silly me, I was indeed expecting XML (SOAP) data. I fixed this a long time ago but forgot to answer my own question so this can be closed.

Comment: To improve the quality of your (own) Answer please explain what you did to fix the problem.  Include a sample of code showing the solution (if practical).  Please include links to any resources that were useful in formulating your solution.  This is so anyone who stumbles across this Question and Answer when researching a similar problem of theirs will have the best chance of finding help.  Also, please Accept your own Answer (if you can) so that the Question does not appear on the list of unanswered Questions anymore.  Finally, congratulations on fixing the problem yourself!  :)